How to combine multiple dependant linear functions into one function
I have 4 variables which affect the performance of a query in my database, and each affect performance linearly. An example of a variable would be the "rowcount" for a specific table.
Therefore I have 4 linear functions:
timeTakenVar1(var1) = var1 * a (with var2, var3, var4 set)

timeTakenVar2(var2) = var2 * b (with var1, var3, var4 set)

timeTakenVar3(var3) = var3 * c (with var1, var2, var4 set)

timeTakenVar4(var4) = var4 * d (with var1, var2, var3 set)

I want to combine these functions into something like this
timeTaken(var1, var2, var3, var4) = var1*a + var2*b + var3*c + var4*d

However, I don't know how the variables depend/affect each other. Creating each of these linear functions took about an hour each, so I cannot test all possible combinations of variables against each other. Which additional tests should I run to incorporate dependencies into the timeTaken function?
